# How to relate tables in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am building a mock question and answer site using mysql as my database. I have 3 tables. Questions, answers, and comments. My question is, how do I relate the comments table to the other two tables, as comments can exist for both.

Comment: And how your database design looks so far?

Comment: Search database subtyping/subtables.

Comment: Can you post for us the design of your database or at least the creation of your tables?